# converting Russian (unicode) characters to English in javascript

Tags: javascript, wsh

I have a long array with actual values of unicode characters and their corresponding English letters, but made this simple example which is not working - I am newish to javascript - this isn't being run from a web page - can you tell me why this isn't working?

```
var str1 = 'онки', 
    st2;         
//should be \u043e\u043d\u043a\u0438 based on converting tool I used

WScript.Echo('before',str1);
str2= str1.replace(/[\u043e\u043d​\u043a\u0438]/g,'X')
WScript.Echo('after',str2);
```

Comment: hard to understand, сложно тебя понять

Comment: What encoding did you save your file as?

Comment: You are using some sort of mix betweeb VBScript and Javascript. I can't get it quite right...

Comment: If you're actually just using JavaScript, `str1.replace(/[онки]/g, 'X')` should work just fine.

Comment: Looks like you are using the Windows Script Host and not pure javascirpt. Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514300/text-encoding-on-wscript-arguments) - it might be useful

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an existing java script which was replace a Line Feed or something, so I guess you're right - it's not real java script - but the code enclosed from the last commentator looks like visual basic.  I'm just running this in windows.

I am calling it from a different programming environment - called Magic, but you can imagine that I am just double clicking on it, like a bat file.  That's how I need it to run like a .bat file.
(Sorry, very new to this site- couldn't even find out how to find my question.)

Does anyone know how I can specify my type of encoding in a java script bat file?

Comment: mode con cp select=1250
Cannot be used directly in the java script - what can I do instead?

Comment: Can you clarify how you use your script? You say it is not run from web page. Is it a windows batch file or something else?